# spring and Android

Tags: android, spring

i'm new in Java technology. My question is : can anyone help me to find a tutorial to integrate spring framework (business and persistence matters) in an Android application (view managing).
Thanks and excuse me if the response can seem obvious.

Comment: you can help community if you mark as answer any post here which you think was more helpful for you